# Elasticsearch : "failed to get node info for {IP}" and "noNodeAvailableException" in service log

Tags: java, spring, docker, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I am facing an issue which i wasn't earlier.

I am attaching logs of my service and elasticSearch (2.4.4):

```
2020-05-30 06:29:44.576  INFO 24787 --- [generic][T#287]] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Shatter] failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{172.17.0.1}{172.17.0.1:9300}, disc
onnecting...

org.elasticsearch.transport.ReceiveTimeoutTransportException: [][172.17.0.1:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness] request_id [10242] timed out after [5000ms]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$TimeoutHandler.run(TransportService.java:698) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_242]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
```

ElasticSearch Logs:

```
[2020-05-30 06:29:46,784][INFO ][monitor.jvm              ] [Tempo] [gc][old][230125][41498] duration [8.2s], collections [1]/[9s], total [8.2s]/[10.7h], memory [473.2mb]->[426.1mb]/[494.9mb], all_pools {[young] [131.8mb]->[84.7mb]/[136.5mb]}{[survivor] [0b]->[0b]/[17mb]}{[old] [341.3mb]->[341.3mb]/[341.3mb]}
[2020-05-30 06:33:47,782][INFO ][monitor.jvm              ] [Tempo] [gc][old][230340][41540] duration [7s], collections [1]/[7.8s], total [7s]/[10.7h], memory [493.3mb]->[425mb]/[494.9mb], all_pools {[young] [136.5mb]->[83.6mb]/[136.5mb]}{[survivor] [15.4mb]->[0b]/[17mb]}{[old] [341.3mb]->[341.3mb]/[341.3mb]}
[2020-05-30 06:37:59,384][INFO ][monitor.jvm              ] [Tempo] [gc][old][230569][41582] duration [6.9s], collections [1]/[7.2s], total [6.9s]/[10.7h], memory [494.8mb]->[424.7mb]/[494.9mb], all_pools {[young] [136.5mb]->[83.4mb]/[136.5mb]}{[survivor] [16.9mb]->[0b]/[17mb]}{[old] [341.3mb]->[341.3mb]/[341.3mb]}
```

i am not facing the issue in my Development environment however when i deploy on EC2 i am getting this. Adding further when i do a restart of elastic. It works absolutely fine with no issues but after 10-15 mins or less depending on the amount for search queries or insertion queries, the error message appears.

Also, my storage space on the instance is 74% consumed 94G out of 120G. 
can it be because of memory ? 
I am pretty much sure my res-client code is fine as its working in production now for a long time. 
Can it be a Port issue ? I am using docker container for elastic.

Any help will be appreciated.

_cat/fielddata?v
[image]

_cat/nodes?v
[image]

Comment: please add /_cat/nodes?v  and /_cat/fielddata?v  response to question

Comment: Can you give the configuration about your es? and any error/warnings logs in elasticsearch

Comment: @jinnaBalu: i am using a dockerized container . the yaml file just has the entry of the IP: 0.0.0.0

Comment: @hamidbayat i have edited the question and i can notice the heap and ram percent to be 96%

Answer (score 1):

I think your heap size for elasticsearch is very low. my best guess is with increasing the heap size the problem will be solved. 
To ask why this has happened now, I think it's because the volume of data has increased over time.

my second guess is about high load. It seems that you have too many request to elasticsearch recently. you can check the size of queue request via `/_cat/thread_pool?v`. 
you have two solution for this situation. first decrease the request. second add a node and add replica.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i had increased the heap size which was set to 512m to 2g.

the heap.percent has gone down to 35 now. However the ram.percent is 99% 

i had changed the configuration  ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g of my docker container. 
any idea about the ram.percent.

apologies for delayed reply.

Comment: dont worry about ram percent. when JVM start, it will take all 2 GB ram (as you config) as heap memory. It doesn't mean that your ram is full. it means that JVM is managing the memory.